# Is there any way to run commands on an Amazon EMR cluster using Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

Like I would like to execute basic commands like mkdir, cd, curl, etc on a cluster, but programmatically using java.

Comment: You do not mean using the EMR Java client. Is that correct?

Comment: Using EMR Java client, I want to execute commands like mkdir, cd, etc in the running cluster

Comment: See my response below that addresses using the ERM Java client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java to perform Amazon EMR operations, like creating a cluster by using the [software.amazon.awssdk.services.emr.EmrClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/emr/EmrClient.html) client. See the following GITHUB repo for code examples.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/emr/src/main/java/aws/example/emr